# Android NDK JNI_OnLoad not getting called

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I am following a tutorial on NDK development using C++. The app is a basic fibonacci number printing app. I have the appropriate System.loadLibrary and the JNI_OnLoad call. I can see in the logcat that the library is getting loaded. However, post that, the system still looks for methods based on the package names. Heres the error from logcat .

```
No implementation found for long com.test.fib.FibLib.fibN(long) (tried Java_com_test_fib_FibLib_fibN and Java_com_test_fib_FibLib_fibN__J)
```

And here is the class where I have the cpp code and related stuff .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>

#define LOG_TAG "Fibonacci Stuff"

#define LOG_D(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

namespace com_test_fib {

    static long fib(long n) {
        if(n==0) return 0;
        if(n==1) return 1;
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    /* JNI wrapper */
    static jlong fibN(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jlong n) {
        return fib(n);
    }

    static JNINativeMethod method_table[] = {
            {"fibN", "(J)J", (void *) fibN }
    };
}

using namespace com_test_fib;
extern "C" jint JNI_Onload(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    LOG_D ("JNI_OnLoad");
    JNIEnv* env;
    if(vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK           ) {
        LOG_D("Initial Get env error");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    else {
        jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/test/fib/FibLib");
        LOG_D ("Find the class");
        if(clazz) {
            LOG_D ("Class not found");
            jint ret = env->RegisterNatives(clazz, method_table, sizeof(method_table)/sizeof(method_table[0]) );
            env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);
            return ret ==0 ? JNI_VERSION_1_6 : JNI_ERR;
        } else {
            LOG_D("Some error it seems");
            return JNI_ERR;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the loadLibrary call

```
package com.test.fib;

import android.util.Log;

public class FibLib {

    public static long fibJ(long n) {
        if(n==0) {
            return 0;
        }   
        if(n==1) {
            return 1;   
        }
        return fibJ(n-1) + fibJ(n-2);
    }

    /* Wrapper to call the JNI code. This is called by the activity */
    public static native long fibN(long n);

    static {
        Log.d("Sys library loading", "This should call the onLoad function");
        System.loadLibrary("Fib");
    }
}
```

I can see the above message in Logcat. After that i directly see the exceptions and no messages from the onLoad method. I am using eclipse, min version is 14 and compile version is 5.1.1. Device is nexus 7. The package names are matching com.test.fib) in the app and the namespace.

Can anyone please let me know whats wrong here. THis is driving me mad..

Thanks

Comment: The logCat message says `Java_com_test_fib_FibLib_fibN` but I don't see `FibLib` anywhere.

Comment: Added that class code; Its a separate java file which contains that class

Comment: Your source code shows `JNI_Onload` rather than `JNI_OnLoad` (note capital 'L').

Comment: Woah.. that worked... i cant belive it was such a stupid mistake. I guess copy pasting is in fact advantageous..... THanks a ton.